# How is the jQuery Highlight style supposed to be applied?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

On the bottom, right hand side of the jQuery Theme Roller, http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/, it shows sample 'Highlight / Error' text.  How should I use this in my projects?

I realise that I could just copy the surrounding markup, but that seems like a hack.  I have used other jQuery widgets where a plugin method is called on the jQuery selection (e.g. `accordion()` or `autocomplete()`).  Does the same apply when applying highlight or error styles?

Comment: They are there for you and plugin authors to use as needed, there is no built-in plugin that uses them currently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is reserved for errors or highlighting as you might assume. You can apply them programmatically, or you can manually add the css class and it will apply

```
    .addClass('ui-state-highlight')
    .addClass('ui-state-error')
```